# How to assign a value to the class attribute corresponding to the value of a specific string variable?

Tags: python, class

As in the question, I have a string variable that may correspond to many values.

I want to assign a value to the corresponding attribute of the class based on the value.
What should I do?

My code is as follows:

This code `c1.__dict__[var1] = 'string'` i want to achieve `c1.value1='string'`。

How should I write the code?

```
class My_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = ''
        self.value2 = ''
        return


def main():
    var1 = 'value1'
    c1 = My_Class()
    c1.__dict__[var1] = 'string'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code does it `print(c1.value1) # string`

Comment: Thank you, there was an error message when I ran it just now, I thought it was a mistake!